# How to properly specify idiosyncratic ICC compiler options in CMake?

Tags: cmake, intel, idioms, icc, buildconfiguration

The Intel C/C++ has a bunch of custom flags, some of which mix compilation and linking, (such as `-qopenmp`), and others are just idiosyncratic alternative forms (such as `-ipp` for linking with Intel's ipp libraries).

I can add such flags "manually" to the compiler flags, and ignore the fact they may have linking implications; or add them both to the compilation and linking flags. But both of these alternatives seem "off". How do I properly work with the various ICC-specific flags in CMake?

Comment: Cmake is supposed to be for cross platform projects and such compiler specific options do not "belong" in the cmakelists ;-). Have you considered a toolchain file instead?

Comment: @André: 1. What is a "toolchain file"? 2. I realize that CMake is cross-platform, but it does have some facilities which translate into compiler-specific options, e.g. `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD` and friends which pass different things to MSVC and GCC/clang. I thought maybe there was something similar - even a module - for these kinds of options.

Comment: Hence the ;-). https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html. It is intended for cross compilation, but I have used it succesfully in the past on compute clusters, supercomputers, etc. to specify hardware specific flags.

Comment: @André: It looks like those files are simply a bunch of CMake commands, most of which I already know. I don't quite see how that would help me. Or - are you saying that if I put the custom icc junk in a toolchain file it's somehow more legitimate?

Answer (score 0):

First looking at: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/release/3.20.html#compilers

> The Intel oneAPI NextGen LLVM compilers are now supported with compiler id `IntelLLVM`:
> The `icx`/`icpx` C/C++ compilers on Linux, and the icx C/C++ compiler on Windows, are fully supported as of oneAPI 2021.1.
> The `ifx` Fortran compiler on Linux is supported as of oneAPI 2021.1.
> The `ifx` Fortran compiler on Windows is not yet supported.
> The Intel oneAPI Classic compilers (`icc`, `icpc`, and `ifort`) continue to be supported with compiler id **`Intel`**.

So If i were you I would use the compiler id `Intel` to pass icc scpecific flags.
ref: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_COMPILER_ID.html

```
if (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID STREQUAL "Intel")
  add_compile_definitions(...) # CMake 3.12
  add_compile_options(...)
  add_link_options(...) # CMake 3.13
endif()
```

ref:

- https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_compile_definitions.html
- https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_compile_options.html
- https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_link_options.html